# Old HTML/CSS files did not update with git push on GitHub

Tags: html, css, git, github

I'm pretty new with GitHub and GitBash, I uploaded (by dragging the files) a folder that included my HTML and CSS files 11 days ago. Today I finally figured out how to push them with the terminal, since I "git push" my whole project, I now have the old html/css files (I dragged and dropped) 11 days before. I thought that those files (from 11 days ago) would be updated with the new code I added to those HTML/CSS files with $git push. Is it possible to combine them so that I can still have the old record but have new updates show? Or would I just need to delete the old (dragged and drop) files?

[image: image included here]

Comment: did you add the files you dragged-and-dropped using git add? You can see which files will be included in a commit by typing git status in the terminal.

Comment: Hi Rob, no I did not, I only dragged and dropped the folder from my desktop.

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you want to achieve. By combining, do you mean you want `index.html` and `style.css` in the root to overwrite the ones in your subdirectory? Because in that case you merely need to put them in the same directory, commit, and push. And what do you mean by 'still having the old record, but having the new updates show'? If you overwrite them, you can access the old versions by accessing the relevant commit.

Comment: Hi Rob, thank you for your response. By having the old records, I meant that the old files would be updated with my new changes instead of having two  duplicate files, one index.html and style.css(uploaded) and one usuing git.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a new branch at the commit where old files are created (11 days ago). "git branch -b test "
2. Move the files out of the folder and commit
3. Apply the rest of commits using "git rebase --onto"

The commands in quotes are not total, but just examples

Comment: Thank you duggi I will attempt this now.

Answer (score 0):

Before pushing, you need to add all files using this command

```
git add .
```

Now commit the changes you made

```
git commit -am "Updating some files(Whatever you want you can write as a comment)"
```

Now push with mentioning remote and branch, usually remote is origin and branch is master

```
git push -u origin master
```

There is a nice tutorial series about git on youtube. You can follow this tutorial from the coding train [Git and Github For Poets](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BCQHnlnPusY&list=PLRqwX-V7Uu6ZF9C0YMKuns9sLDzK6zoiV) by Daniel Shiffman.

Comment: Thank you @Robin, this is very very helpful. Thanks for adding the tutorial video as well. Cheers!